# Save as XML with VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, excel

Is there any way to save an Excel table as XML? I have the XML Schema file... and some data in a table... and I have in Excel the Save as XML file option but can I save a file as XML from VBA? I want to automate a process and I didn;t find nothing on this option. Thanks!

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766760/how-to-generate-xml-from-an-excel-vba-macro

Comment: That piece of code converts the data from a table... it's ok and will be the ultimate solution but I have the XML schema file ..and I want to do everything with the options Excel already has ... I'll try to record a macro to see if there is something useful.

Comment: so... what I want is a VBA code that will load the xml scema... will do what it does when I drag/drop it over the table... than use the Save as and save it as XML

Comment: Try recording a macro and see what it does :)

Comment: That's what I did :)) It works great :))

Comment: +1 for you for learning something new on your own ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the good ol' macro recorder saved me this time :)) (Why didn't I used it before I posted here?)
So...
To load an xml schema you have:

```
ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add("Book2.xml", "raport").Name _
        = "raport_Map"
```

And to save it as xml:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAsXMLData Filename:="Book3.xml", _
        Map:=ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("raport_Map")
```

Who would have thought that it's that easy?

Comment: +1) Gr8 Job! It's really fun when you discover something on your own. Isn't it ;)

Comment: I wasn't aware of xml mapping before reading your answer and I want to add an useful piece of info for those in the same case as me: [Creating an XML Mapping Schema in Excel 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg469857%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me the most -> http://curiousmind.jlion.com/exceltotextfile

Script on link:

```
Sub MakeXML(iCaptionRow As Integer, iDataStartRow As Integer, sOutputFileName As String)
    Dim Q As String
    Q = Chr$(34)

    Dim sXML As String

    sXML = "<?xml version=" & Q & "1.0" & Q & " encoding=" & Q & "UTF-8" & Q & "?>"
    sXML = sXML & "<rows>"


    ''--determine count of columns
    Dim iColCount As Integer
    iColCount = 1
    While Trim$(Cells(iCaptionRow, iColCount)) > ""
        iColCount = iColCount + 1
    Wend

    Dim iRow As Integer
    iRow = iDataStartRow

    While Cells(iRow, 1) > ""
        sXML = sXML & "<row id=" & Q & iRow & Q & ">"

        For icol = 1 To iColCount - 1
           sXML = sXML & "<" & Trim$(Cells(iCaptionRow, icol)) & ">"
           sXML = sXML & Trim$(Cells(iRow, icol))
           sXML = sXML & "</" & Trim$(Cells(iCaptionRow, icol)) & ">"
        Next

        sXML = sXML & "</row>"
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Wend
    sXML = sXML & "</rows>"

    Dim nDestFile As Integer, sText As String

    ''Close any open text files
    Close

    ''Get the number of the next free text file
    nDestFile = FreeFile

    ''Write the entire file to sText
    Open sOutputFileName For Output As #nDestFile
    Print #nDestFile, sXML
    Close
End Sub

Sub test()
    MakeXML 1, 2, "C:\Users\jlynds\output2.xml"
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the original link is down. But you can access a capture from 2013 here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130502005831/http://curiousmind.jlion.com/exceltotextfile