# Saving the document

Tags: excel, vba

How to enter a variable into the code correctly so that the saved document has a name, which is located in cell A1

```
ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("Pi").Export Url:="C:\Users\nico\Desktop\A1.XML"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit 

Sub SaveMe() 
     'Saves filename as value of A1 

    Dim newFile As String, fName As String 
    fName = Range("A1").Value 
    newFile = fName 

    ChDir _ 
    "C:\Users\nico\Desktop\" 
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newFile 

End Sub
```

Comment: The solution creates a file in xlsm format, I would like to get the exported XML file. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Please refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558013/save-as-xml-with-vba