# Excel Data to XML

Tags: excel, vba, automation

Need to convert excel data into XML format.

```
'vba code to convert excel to xml
  Sub vba_code_to_convert_excel_to_xml()
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\testwb.xlsx")
 wb.SaveAs fileName:="C:\temp\testX.xml", FileFormat:= _
    xlXMLSpreadsheet, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

Kindly let me how to do this in VBA or provide a link where I can refer. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save as XML with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558013/save-as-xml-with-vba)

Comment: Here's a good place to start https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqAxQ5jUK5Q

Comment: Is your real data more complex than just 4 columns ?

Comment: No, my real data is the same as like this @CDP1802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple case one way would be to build the xml line by line

```vb
Sub vba_code_to_convert_excel_to_xml2()

    Const FOLDER = "C:\temp\"
    Const XLS_FILE = "testwb.xlsx"
    Const XML_FILE = "testX.xml"

    Const XML = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & vbCrLf & _
                 "<Core-Information ContextID=""Context1"" WorkspaceID=""Main"">" & vbCrLf & _
                 "  <UserList>" & vbCrLf
                 
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, ar, s As String
    Dim iLastRow As Long, r As Long, n As Integer

    ' open source workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & XLS_FILE, 1, 1)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' create XML document
    '<User ID="Aravind" ForceAuthentication="false" Password="1234" EMail="Aravind@gmail.com">
    '    <Name>Aravind</Name>
    '    <UserGroupLink UserGroupID="Sports"/>
    '</User>
    s = XML
    For r = 2 To iLastRow
        s = s & "    <User ID=""" & ws.Cells(r, 1) & """" & _
            " ForceAuthentication=""false"" Password=""" & ws.Cells(r, 2) & """" & _
            " EMail=""" & ws.Cells(r, 3) & """>" & vbCrLf
        s = s & "      <Name>" & ws.Cells(r, 1) & "</Name>" & vbCrLf
     
        ar = Split(ws.Cells(r, 4), ",")
        For n = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
            s = s & "      <UserGroupLink UserGroupID=""" & Trim(ar(n)) & """/>" & vbCrLf
        Next

        s = s & "    </User>" & vbCrLf
    Next
    s = s & "  </UserList>" & vbCrLf & "</Core-Information>"
    
    ' save
    Dim fso, ts
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.createtextfile(FOLDER & XML_FILE)
    ts.write s
    ts.Close
    MsgBox "Xml created to " & FOLDER & XML_FILE

End Sub
```