# Does a faster alternative to ADODB.Stream exist?

Tags: xml, vba, file, ms-word, openxml

I have been reading and writing utf-8 files in my VBA application with some success using `ADODB.Stream`.  The only real problem is that `ADODB.Stream` is rather slow compared to native VBA file reading.  Ordinarily, I would use the stock VBA `Open`, `Input`, `Print`, `Close`, etc. functions, which are fast enough.  I haven't tried any Windows API or DLL solution as the tendency is, right or wrong, to disable API calls, DLLs, and so on.

I use this to edit the Open Office XML files of a group of documents before merging them together.

Here are my read and write functions for utf-8 files.  These were copied from the internet.

```
Public Function readUtf8(fn As String) As String
    Dim stream As ADODB.stream: Set stream = New ADODB.stream
    stream.Charset = "utf-8"
    stream.Open
    On Error GoTo nofile
    stream.LoadFromFile fn
    readUtf8 = stream.ReadText() & ""
    stream.Close
    Set stream = Nothing
    Exit Function

nofile:
    stream.Close
    Set stream = Nothing
    readUtf8 = ""
End Function
```

The write function is more or less the same thing in reverse.

```
Public Function writeUtf8(fn As String, txt As String) As Integer
    Dim stream As ADODB.stream: Set stream = New ADODB.stream
    stream.Charset = "utf-8"
    stream.Open
    stream.WriteText txt
    stream.SaveToFile fn
    stream.Close
    Set stream = Nothing
    writeUtf8 = 0

End Function
```

Is there a faster alternative to `ADODB.Stream`?

Comment: Have you tried any other methods for writing to a file? Which ones, and how are they not satisfactory? It's rather difficult for us to make suggestions, not knowing what you're already tried... FWIW my inclination for writing XML documents would be to use the XML DOM, as described in the response by Siddharth Rout here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1af3588-fe8f-492f-88e9-dd72fca624bf/write-xml-entry-with-excel-vba?forum=exceldev or in the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766760/how-to-generate-xml-from-an-excel-vba-macro

Comment: XML oriented solution noted