# Converting Excel to XML - Output format problem

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have a task to create XML files from excel files that need to be fed into a database system.
I got the code from the forum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766760/how-to-generate-xml-from-an-excel-vba-macro/22375724).

I modified it as per the output I need but something isn't right and can't figure out what.
I am hoping you guys can help me out.

This is the output I am getting with the VBA.
[image]
As you can see, something goes wrong after the 'ConsigneeAdress1' tag.

Below is the exact format of the output I need.
[image]

Below is the code I am Using.

```html
Sub MakeXML()
Dim iCaptionRow As Integer
Dim iDataStartRow As Integer
Dim sOutputFileName As String
    Dim Q As String
    Q = Chr$(34)

    Dim sXML As String

    sXML = "<?xml version=" & Q & "1.0" & Q & " encoding=" & Q & "UTF-8" & Q & "?>"
    sXML = sXML & "<Manifest><Header><Version>2.13</Version><AccountNumber/><PackageCount>155</PackageCount><FileDateTime>2021-12-09 10:28</FileDateTime><TimeZone>UTC</TimeZone><FileName>Manifest--PRDZARA-00075955.xml</FileName><Warehouse/><WarehouseCode/><BrandCode/></Header>"


    ''--determine count of columns
    Dim iColCount As Integer
    iColCount = 1
    iCaptionRow = 1
    While Trim(Cells(iCaptionRow, iColCount)) > ""
        iColCount = iColCount + 1
    Wend

    Dim iRow As Integer
    iDataStartRow = 2
    iRow = iDataStartRow

    While Cells(iRow, 1) > ""
        sXML = sXML & "<Package>"
        For icol = 1 To iColCount - 1
           sXML = sXML & "<" & Trim(Cells(iCaptionRow, icol)) & ">"
           sXML = sXML & Trim(Cells(iRow, icol))
           sXML = sXML & "</" & Trim(Cells(iCaptionRow, icol)) & ">"
        Next

        sXML = sXML & "</Package>"
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Wend
    sXML = sXML & "</Manifest>"

debug.print sXML
   
End Sub
```

If you guys can help me figure out what exactly is going wrong, I'll be really grateful.

EDIT:
Actual text output from VBA.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Manifest><Header><Version>2.13</Version><AccountNumber/><PackageCount>155</PackageCount><FileDateTime>2021-12-09 10:28</FileDateTime><TimeZone>UTC</TimeZone><FileName>Manifest--PRDZARA-00075955.xml</FileName><Warehouse/><WarehouseCode/><BrandCode/></Header><Package><EswShipmentReference>6001012837067</EswShipmentReference><CustomerReference>420114379400109898642807925833</CustomerReference><CarrierId></CarrierId><CarrierReference></CarrierReference><ServiceLevel></ServiceLevel><CarrierServiceDescription></CarrierServiceDescription><EventCode></EventCode><EventReasonCode></EventReasonCode><Weight>0.1</Weight><WeightUnit>LBS</WeightUnit><VolumetricWeight></VolumetricWeight><VolumetricWeightUnit></VolumetricWeightUnit><DimUnit>IN</DimUnit><DimHeight>3.4</DimHeight><DimLength>11.8</DimLength><DimWidth>5</DimWidth><ShippingValue></ShippingValue><ShippingValueCurrencyCode></ShippingValueCurrencyCode><ProcessedDate></ProcessedDate><BillingCharge></BillingCharge><ConsigneeAddress1></ConsigneeAddress1><ConsigneeAddress2></ConsigneeAddress2><ConsigneeCity></ConsigneeCity><ConsigneeRegion></ConsigneeRegion><ConsigneePostalCode></ConsigneePostalCode><ConsigneeCountry>NZ</ConsigneeCountry><PalletId></PalletId><AdditionalCarrierData1></AdditionalCarrierData1><AdditionalCarrierData2></AdditionalCarrierData2><AdditionalCarrierData3></AdditionalCarrierData3><AdditionalCarrierData4></AdditionalCarrierData4><AdditionalCarrierData5></AdditionalCarrierData5></Package><Package><EswShipmentReference>6001012837068</EswShipmentReference><CustomerReference>420114379400109898642807925832</CustomerReference><CarrierId></CarrierId><CarrierReference></CarrierReference><ServiceLevel></ServiceLevel><CarrierServiceDescription></CarrierServiceDescription><EventCode></EventCode><EventReasonCode></EventReasonCode><Weight>0.3</Weight><WeightUnit>LBS</WeightUnit><VolumetricWeight></VolumetricWeight><VolumetricWeightUnit></VolumetricWeightUnit><DimUnit>IN</DimUnit><DimHeight>3.5</DimHeight><DimLength>12</DimLength><DimWidth>6</DimWidth><ShippingValue></ShippingValue><ShippingValueCurrencyCode></ShippingValueCurrencyCode><ProcessedDate></ProcessedDate><BillingCharge></BillingCharge><ConsigneeAddress1></ConsigneeAddress1><ConsigneeAddress2></ConsigneeAddress2><ConsigneeCity></ConsigneeCity><ConsigneeRegion></ConsigneeRegion><ConsigneePostalCode></ConsigneePostalCode><ConsigneeCountry>AU</ConsigneeCountry><PalletId></PalletId><AdditionalCarrierData1></AdditionalCarrierData1><AdditionalCarrierData2></AdditionalCarrierData2><AdditionalCarrierData3></AdditionalCarrierData3><AdditionalCarrierData4></AdditionalCarrierData4><AdditionalCarrierData5></AdditionalCarrierData5></Package></Manifest>
```

Comment: The image you show is for sure not the output from the code, there was already an instance that modified it: You never write <tag/> for empty tags.

Comment: Hi @FunThomas, I'm not too familiar with XML honestly. And Barely comfortable with VBA. So I don't understand what you mean by never write <tag/> for empty tags. And which image are you pointing at? The desired output or the actual output of the the VBA

Comment: I refer to the upper image that you labelled *"This is the output I am getting with the VBA."*. If you have an empty cell, lets say EventCode, you write <EventCode></EventCode>. However, the image shows <\EventCode> which is a valid XML shortcut for an empty tag - but you don't write it that way.

Comment: Hi @FunThomas, looks like you are correct. I pasted the output in Notepad++ which I think is changing the format. Editing the question to add the actual text output. Could you please confirm for me if the output is correct and a valid XML file?

Comment: The XML is fine. You can add some line breaks on the closing tags `sXML = sXML & "</" & Trim(Cells(iCaptionRow, icol)) & ">" & vbCrLf`. Use the XMLTools plugin for Notepad++.

Comment: Do you actually need the tags without values in the XML ?

Comment: @CDP1802, Not sure honestly if those empty tags are needed. I am just trying to replicate an XML that I have from the system. No sure if we skip the empty tags, the system will still process the file.

Comment: Side note: mabe of some interest as regarding closing tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67071835/vba-with-xslt-to-pretty-print-xml-with-end-tags-in-the-same-line

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for troubling you guys.
Figured out what the problem was.

I was copy pasting the text from the immediate window to Notepad++.
The word wrap on the immediate window caused the line breaks on Notepad++ pretty print format which caused all the issue.

So it came down to me for being stupid and unfamiliar with XML encoding.

Also thanks to @CDP1802 for giving the idea of adding the line feed directly in the VBA for getting the right formatting.

And the original code itself works as expected.